# $_Get variable not working

Tags: php, math, rounding

I'm Jad and I'm trying to make a math rounder.
The problem is that when I click Do Math!, the echo doesn't work.
Here's my code:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['math']))
    switch ($_GET['math']) {
        case "round":
            if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
                echo round($_POST['numb1']); 
            } else{
                ?>
                <h1>Math Rounding!</h1>
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post">         
                    <table border="0">
                        <tr>
                           <td>Number:</td>
                           <td>
                               <input type="text" name="numb1" placeholder="Number 1..." maxlength="44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444">
                           </td>
                       </tr>
                       <tr>
                           <th colspan=2>
                              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Do Math!" style="height: 25px; width: 100px">
                           </th>
                      </tr>
                    </table>
                </form>
                </center>
                <?php 
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Use `print_r($_GET);` to see what you've sent in your form. Aha - your method should be `get` not `post` - then change your `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Comment: ^^Can you please give me the whole new echo/print?

Comment: Your form submission method is post. So use $_POST or $_REQUEST. And also there is no math in your form.

Comment: For a start, your markup is wrong, you're closing a non-existant `<tr><td>` and you've got a `</center>` in there too. This also smells like homework.

Comment: is math is present in url

Comment: @Anshad, since the effect is idempotent, and there is no private information in the query string, GET is more suitable imo.

Comment: @Jamie that's because I didn't give you the whole code.

Comment: @halfer then the form method should be changed to GET right ?

Comment: @Anshad, yes indeed - see my first comment.

Comment: Just a side comment :) But those are alot of 4's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in each form change the value of hidden field(`<input type="hidden" name="math" value="round">`) acoordingly.and also need to change the forms action to a single page.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['math']))
{
switch ($_POST['math'])
{
case "round":

echo round($_POST['numb1']);
exit;
case "round1":
echo round($_POST['numb1']);
exit;

}
 }      
else{
?>
<h1>Math Rounding!</h1>
<form action="<?php
echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
?>" method="post">


<input type="hidden" name="math" value="round">


<table border="0">
<tr><td>Number:</td><td>
<input type="text" name="numb1" placeholder="Number 1..." maxlength="44444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444444">
</td></tr>
<tr><th colspan=2><input type="submit" name="submit" 
value="Do Math!" style="height: 25px; width: 100px"></th></tr></table>
</form>
</center>
<?php 


}?>
```

Comment: Wait no, I want it to work with more than one ?math=, this only works with one ?math.

Comment: make the input type as select box and write the code accordingly in php

Comment: What?How do I do this?

Comment: check the edited code...you can add more options in select box and corresponding case on submission...

Comment: Yeah but each one has it's own form.

Comment: check the edited code....add the hidden field in each form and put the value accordingly...and write the code accordingly in php.You need to also change the  action of all the forms to single page...

Comment: I tried my best but didn't work :l please give me the full code(with the second type of html).

Comment: do you have different files for different files or all the forms in signle file?

Comment: please email me all your files with exact requirement....because i am unable to understand your requirement (vikasumrao@sify.com)

Comment: I'm trying to make a calculator, math.php?math=round, ?math=operators, and ?math=compare. I want a code which I can use all 3, and each one has a html.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set method to "get" and set form action to "" instead of   .There is no need for it.

Your program should work now :)
edit:
set

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">
```

to

```
<form action="" method="get">
```

Comment: What do you mean? Please give me the whole new code. I'm new at php.

Comment: I think a form without an action might be invalid HTML - browsers will tolerate it though. However, I'd be inclined to leave the `PHP_SELF` where it is.

Comment: No it is not. empty action redirects you to the same page so there is no need to put in PHP_SELF in action. It is a matter of personal choice :) , both will work.

Comment: Just checked that for HTML5 at the W3C Validator, you are nearly right - removing the `action` attribute is permitted, but not if it is present but empty. I just learnt something `:)`

Comment: ^ I updated my earlier comment. Turns out that an empty action, rather than omitting the action entirely, is invalid HTML. You're right that browsers will tolerate it, but we should be promoting valid markup too.